# Change the text on a single line number in multiple text files

Tags: text-processing, awk, vi, bash-script

Suppose that I have ten bash shell scripts: `script1.sh`, `script2.sh`, ..., `script10.sh`.  Initially, all ten files are identical.

Now, I would like to make two changes in each script:

1. In each file, I would like to change a particular line (say line 8) -- that is, deleting whatever is on line 8 and replacing it with a *"constant"* string that I specify, such as `"This is line 8."`  This is similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70878/replacing-string-based-on-line-number), but there they wanted to replace `"AAA"` with `"BBB"`, whereas I would like to replace line 8 (whatever it is) with `"This is line 8."`.
2. In each file, I would like to change another particular line (say line 21) and replace it with a *"variable"* string that I specify.  For example, in `script1.sh` I want to change line 21 to `"XYZ"`; in `script2.sh` I want to change line 21 to `"PQR"`; and in `script3.sh` I want to change line 21 to `"ABC"`.  Essentially this is just many calls to the function in **(1)** above -- except that I would be making the change in one individual file rather than in all files, and that I am specifying ten different strings rather than just one.  So to obtain **(2)** here, perhaps I would just call **(1)** ten different times with different parameters.

I am interested in solutions that use commonly available Linux programs like `bash`, `vi`, `awk`, `gawk`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for file in f1 f2; do
  sed -i '8s/^.*$/foo/' "$file"
done
```

Comment: Why not just `sed -i '8s/^.*$/foo/' f1 f2`?

Comment: @l0b0 Have you tried that?

Comment: Worked perfectly: `echo test1 > f1; echo test2 > f2; sed -i '1s/^.*$/foo/' f1 f2`. `cat f1 f2` shows that both were changed to `foo`.

Comment: @l0b0 That's funny. I tried that first but without `-i`. And in that case just one line was changed. Doesn't make sense to me. A bug (GNU sed-Version 4.2.1)?

Comment: Try with `-s`: "consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream."

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
for file in script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh ... script10.sh; do
    temp=$(mktemp)
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            line8 = "This is line 8"
            line21["script1.sh"] = "XYZ"
            line21["script2.sh"] = "PQR"
            line21["script3.sh"] = "ABC"
            # ... 
        }
        FNR == 8 { print line8; next }
        FNR == 21 && FILENAME in line21 { print line21[FILENAME]; next }
        {print}
    '  "$file" > "$temp" && mv "$temp" "$file"
done
```

or, using bash and sed

```
# bash variables to store new values. requires bash v4 for the associative array
line8="This is line 8"
declare -A line21=(
    [script1.sh]="XYZ"
    [script2.sh]="PQR"
    [script3.sh]="ABC"
    # ...
)
# then use sed
for file in script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh ... script10.sh; do
    sed -i "8s/.*/$line8/; 21s/.*/${line21[$file]}/" "$file"
done
```

With the sed solution, you have to be careful that the new lines do not contain "/" characters,
   as that will break the `s///` command. Although you can use different
   delimiter characters, such as `s|pattern|replacement|` (in which case the
   same warning applies, recursively)

`ed` works too:

```
for file in script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh ... script10.sh; do
    ed "$file" <<ED_COMMANDS
8d
8i
$line8
.
21d
21i
${line21[$file]}
.
w
q
ED_COMMANDS
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I will answer both questions but, as a general rule, please don't combine questions like this, split them into separate posts instead.

## Question 1

1. Perl:

   ```
   for f in *.sh; do 
     perl -i -lne '$.==8 ? print "This is line 8" : print;' "$f"; 
   done
   ```
2. awk and variants:

   ```
   for f in *.sh; do 
     awk '{if(NR==8){print "This is line 8"}else{print}}' "$f" > fifo && 
     mv fifo "$f";
   done
   ```

## Question 2

I would first create a file with the replacements I want to make. For example:

```
script1.sh  foo1
script2.sh  foo2
script3.sh  foo3
script4.sh  foo4
```

Then read that file to perform the substitutions:

```
while read f s; do 
 export s;
 perl -i -lne '$.==8 ? print "$ENV{s}" : print;' "$f";
done < sublist.txt
```